# Single source C++ programming model?

Tags: opencl, sycl

What is mean by single source c++ programming model.I have recently came to know about SYCL which people describes it as a Single source C++ programming model related to OPENCL. I would highly appreciate the answers which describes what SYCL is ? and how it works ? 
Thank you guys!

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://www.khronos.org/sycl

Comment: Zindarod - Thanks a lot. I'm new to these stuff s. Can you provide me a simple example to demonstrate it's working please ?

Comment: Following the link @Zindarod shared, you can find this presentation which includes a simple example: http://www.leehowes.com/files/talks/20150512-IWOCL2015-SYCLTutorial-IntroductionToSYCL.pdf

Comment: Dithermaster Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single source programming means that you can keep all your source code in a single file, rather than with OpenCL where kernels live in their own individual files.

You can find out more about SYCL at the link @Zinadarod posted and at http://sycl.tech where there are videos and articles on SYCL. You can find an actual implementation of SYCL [here](https://developer.codeplay.com), with that website also providing a [beginners guide to SYCL](https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/sycl-guide-hello-sycl) as well as resource on how to build software using ComputeCpp, an implementation of SYCL.